# ASP.NET Core 3.1 database context for SQL Server adding a decimal value, results in 10 times that value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, decimal, dbcontext, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core project I'm working on and I'm recording in SQL Server a decimal value.

In "Development" environment I have a SQLite database and there the add works as it should.

When I transition to Production with a SQL Server 2017 instance the insert of (example) 8.0m results in the record having written 80.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Posting the schema, sample data and the code you are trying will get you better help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
Hours = decimal.Parse(hours);
```

this was my previous code and apparently the parsing is not correct for SQL Server without a provider.
Ergo I changed to this.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Hours = decimal.Parse(hours, provider);
```

This seems to solve my issue.